# Does davis safety lamp detect explosive gases in ship compartments?

Tags: safety, gas-phase-chemistry

I feel managers at Bangladesh ship breaking yard are not properly caring for safety of workers. Many workers die in explosions while salvaging metal.  documentary available  on YouTube by National Geographic Channel.

My question is does Davis safety lamp work in compartments  of a ship since it detects explosive gases in coal mines.

Comment: A safety lamp does not necessarily *detect* explosive gases... its fine screen just prevents propagation of the flame from inside to outside. There are cheap VOC detectors, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/methane-detector/s?k=methane+detector .

Comment: It _deflects_ rather than detects. Also yes, it should work in ship compartments. But wait... is that the primary reason for the explosions? Do the guys in Chittagong use open fire for lighting? I highly doubt that.

Comment: Sure, and you can't put them behind the Davy's safety mesh. So the said device is hardly of any help.

Comment: @Dr.Moishe " miners learnt to show the presence of firedamp by looking for changes in the shape and colour of their candle flames. For example, on approaching danger, the tip changed from yellow to greenish-blue". Secondly, $30 is a huge amount in bangladesh. They can't send every gas cutter with a voc

Comment: Early 19th century safety technology is a bad substitute for early 20th century workplace safety regulations. And yes, those companies *can* afford proper ventilation and gas detectors. It's just a matter of establishing and *enforcing* regulations.